# Use pdfplumber to find text in PDF, return page number, then return table

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I downloaded 42 PDFs which are each formatted similarly. Each has various tables, one of which is labeled "Campus Reported Incidents." That particular table is on a different page in each PDF. I want to write a function that will search for the page that has "Campus Reported Incidents" and scrape that table so that I can put it into a dataframe.

I figured that I could use PDFPlumber to search for the string "Campus Reported Incidents" and return the page number. I would then write a function that uses the page number to scrape the table I want, and I would loop that function through every PDF. However, I keep on getting the error "argument is not iterable" or "type object is not subscriptable." I looked through the PDFPlumber documentation but it didn't help my problem.

Here is one example of code that I tried:

```
url = "pdfs/example.pdf"

import pdfplumber

pdf = pdfplumber.open(url)

for page in range[0:len(pdf.pages)]:
    if 'Total number of physical restraints' in pdf.pages[page]:
        print(pdf.page_number)
```

Answer (score 17):

I see this post was from a while ago but maybe this response will still help you or someone else.

The error looks like it's coming from the way you are looping through the pages. The `range` object is not a list, which is why you're seeing the `"type object is not subscriptable"` error message. Instead, try to `"Enumerate"` through the pages. The `"i"` will give you access to the index (aka current count in the loop). The `"pg"`, will give you access to the page object in the PDF pages. I didn't use the `"pg"` variable below, but you could use that instead of `"pages[i]"` if you want.

The code below should print the tables from each page, as well as give you access to the tables to manipulate them further.

```py
import pdfplumber
pdf_file = "pdfs/example.pdf"
tables=[]
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for i,pg in enumerate(pages):
        tbl = pages[i].extract_tables()
        print(f'{i} --- {tbl}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with pdfplumber.

It should be range() not range[].

Please try below:

```
url = "pdfs/example.pdf"

import pdfplumber

pdf = pdfplumber.open(url)

for page in range(0:len(pdf.pages)):
    if 'Total number of physical restraints' in pdf.pages[page]:
        print(pdf.page_number)
```

Comment: It seems you have got some error here.

...`range(0:len(pdf.pages)):`